# Pass arguments to function in React (API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Today I started learning React, and I want to fetch movies from the TMDb API. I have this code:

```
getMovies() {
 const APIKey = "MYAPI";
 fetch(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/company?api_key=${APIKey}&query=${argument}&page=1`)
 .then(function(response) {
   return response.json();
 })
 .then(function(myJson) {
  console.log(myJson);
 });
}
```

And in my render() I have this:

```
return (
  <Fragment>
    <div className="Main">
      <button onClick={this.getMovies.bind('spider-man')}>Get</button>
    </div>
  </Fragment>
)
```

I want to pass 'spider-man' as an argument to do the search in the TMDb API. Hope you can help me!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can pass the parameter to the class component function, using `{() => {...}}` or other option could be `this.getMovies.bind(this, 'spider-man')`

```
getMovies(movie) { // your code here}
```

**Option 1:**

```
return (
  <Fragment>
    <div className="Main">
      <button onClick={() => this.getMovies('spider-man')}>Get</button>
    </div>
  </Fragment>
)
```

**Option 2:**

```
return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="Main">
          <button onClick={() => this.getMovies.bind(this,'spider-man')}>Get</button>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly divided into two categories

1. Class components
2. Functional Components

**Class components**

Consider you have your code as follow:

```
getMovies(movieName){...}

render(){
    <button onClick={/*Attach event here*/}>Get</button>
}
```

There can be 4 ways

1. Using binding in the constructor, This is a recommended way of binding a method.

```
class Movie{
   constructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.getMovies = this.getMovies.bind(this);
   }
   getMovies(movieName){ //your code }
   render(){
       <button onClick={this.getMovies('some_movie_name')}>Get</button>
   }
}
```

2. Using binding in the render method itself. In terms of performance, it's the same as the previous one. The first one is a little cleaner for me.

```
class Movie{
   getMovies(movieName){ //your code }
   render(){
       <button onClick={this.getMovies.bind('some_movie_name')}>Get</button>
   }
}
```

3. Using arrow function syntax in render().

```
class Movie{
   getMovies(movieName){ //your code }
   render(){
       <button onClick={()=>this.getMovies('some_movie_name')}>Get</button>
   }
}
```

4. Using the arrow function in classes. This will have an impact on overall performance. You can read more about this [here](https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1).

```
class Movie{
   getMovies = (movieName) => { //your code }
   render(){
       <button onClick={this.getMovies('some_movie_name')}>Get</button>
   }
}
```

**Function components**

Consider you have your code as follow:

```
function getMovies(movieName){ //your code }

return(){
    <button onClick={/*Attach event here*/}>Get</button>
}
```

1. There aren't many variations for the function component. Using either an arrow or regular function expression to define a function.

```
function Movie(){
   function getMovies(movieName){...} //or const getMovies = (movieName) => {...}

   return(
      <button onClick={()=>getMovies('some_movie_name')}>Get</button>
      {/*
       if not arguments
       <button onClick={getMovies}>Get</button>
     */}
  )
}
```